# Maya for animation - Can you manipulate a selected object without clicking?

Tags: maya

I'm getting into animation in Maya, and I'd really love to speed up my ability to manipulate controls so that I can quickly get my rigs posed. I hope that there would be a way to select with one click, and either rotate, scale, or grab it with one keypress(currently I feel forced to mouse over and middle click the manipulator).

Is there a way to accomplish this kind of efficiency?
What do you use to quickly pose your rigs during animation?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.

Comment: One possibility is scripting some of these tasks, but unless you have a specific problem with that script, this question is off topic for SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a option in preferences under *Settings → Selection* called **click drag select**. Which eliminates the need to select then manipulate. Dragging after initial click now manipulates with whatever manipulator you have enabled. Because this is a programming resource, lets discuss how to do this in your code.  You can toggle this attribute with following mel snippet:

```
selectPref -clickDrag (!`selectPref -q -clickDrag`);
```

Drag the above to your shelf from the command line or script editor. Now you can enable or disable it whenever you want.

Comment: Thank you Joojaa.
Sorry everyone, I'll be more on point in the future for SO.